# NOCYCLE in Postgres

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, connect-by

I have a Oracle query with a `NOCYCLE` clause which I have to translate to Postgres:

```
SELECT FG_ID,CONNECT_BY_ROOT FG_ID as Parent_ID  
FROM FG t
START WITH t.Parent_filter_group_id is null 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR t.FILTER_GROUP_ID = t.PARENT_FILTER_GROUP_ID
```

I have converted this one with the help of the question and answer in 
[connect_by_root equivalent in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296248/connect-by-root-equivalent-in-postgres)

as

```
with recursive fg_tree as (
select FG_ID,
       FG_ID as fg
from  FG
where Parent_filter_group_id is null 

union all 
select c.FG_ID,
p.fg
from FG c join fg_tree p on p.FG_ID = PARENT_FILTER_GROUP_ID
)
select * from fg_tree
order by FG_ID
```

but in this there is no clause for `NOCYCLE` if the parent is also one of the children then this query will return error.

Comment: The documentation on recursive queries gives an example of using an array to prevent cycles:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html.

Comment: Thanks@Gordon Linoff documentation is usefull

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can collect the IDs for each level and then join on the condition that the "current" id is not contained in the path:

```
with recursive fg_tree as (
  select FG_ID,
         FG_ID as fg, 
         array[fg_id] as path
  from  FG
  where Parent_filter_group_id is null 

  union all 

  select c.FG_ID,
         p.fg, 
         p.fg||c.fg_id
  from FG c 
    join fg_tree p on p.FG_ID and c.fg_id <> ALL (p.path)
)
select fg_id, fg 
from fg_tree
order by filter_group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

oracle version:

```
SELECT     o.object_id, p.plugin_id AS plugin_id, LEVEL, CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE "Cycle"
FROM       sst_cycle_obj o LEFT JOIN sst_cycle_devplug p ON p.device_id = o.object_id
WHERE      CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE o.object_id = PRIOR p.plugin_id
START WITH o.object_id = 11

create table sst_cycle_obj
    (object_id numeric(10))


create table sst_cycle_devplug
(device_id numeric(10)
,plugin_id numeric(10)) 


insert into sst_cycle_obj (object_id) 
(select 11 from dual
union all
select 12 from dual
union all
select 13 from dual)

insert into sst_cycle_devplug (device_id,plugin_id) 
(select 11, 12 from dual
union all
select 12, 13 from dual
union all
select 13,11 from dual)

-->NOCYCLE2 CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE "Cycle" Postgresql version
WITH recursive ncot
    AS
         (SELECT a.device_id,a.plugin_id,('{'||a.device_id||'}')::numeric[] as PATH, 0 AS cycle1, 1::int as level
          FROM   ( select o.object_id device_id, p.plugin_id as plugin_id
                    from sst_cycle_obj o 
                    left join sst_cycle_devplug p on p.device_id=o.object_id 
                     ) a
          WHERE  a.device_id = 11
          UNION ALL
          SELECT objt.device_id,objt.plugin_id, ncot.path||objt.device_id::numeric as PATH, CASE WHEN objt.plugin_id = any(ncot.path) THEN 1 else 0 END AS cycle1, ncot.level + 1 as level
          FROM   ( select o.object_id device_id, p.plugin_id as plugin_id
                    from sst_cycle_obj o 
                    left join sst_cycle_devplug p on p.device_id=o.object_id 
                     ) objt
                 JOIN ncot ON objt.device_id = ncot.plugin_id and objt.device_id <> ALL (ncot.path)
                 )
 SELECT device_id,plugin_id,PATH,cycle1,level
 FROM   ncot    
 WHERE cycle1=1
--<
```