# Is there a faster way than LIKE to RECURSIVELY join in SQL-Server, without cycles?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-cte, sql-server-2019

I need to recursively JOIN a large graph that can have cycles.
Now, a dumbed down version of that looks like this in SQL-Server:

```
-- Array:10'000:   1.6s (postgresql)
-- LIKE: 10'000:  19s (sql-server)
-- JSON: 10'000:  19s (sql-server)
-- XML : 10'000:  +infinity  s (sql-server)
-- XML : 300 (a): 17s (nullable) (sql-server)
-- XML : 300 (b): 17s (not nullable) (sql-server)
-- XML : 300 (c): 23s (nullable, xpath) (sql-server)

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        1 AS i
       ,CAST(N',1,' AS national character varying(MAX)) AS paths 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
         CTE.i+1 AS i 
        ,CTE.paths + CAST((CTE.i + 1) AS national character varying(36)) + N',' AS paths
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CTE.i < 10000
    AND CTE.paths LIKE (N'%,' + CAST((CTE.i) AS national character varying(36)) + N',%') 
)
SELECT i FROM CTE 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Since SQL-Server doesn't support arrays, I tried to optimize by using JSON:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
         1 AS i
        ,CAST('[1]' AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS paths

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
         CTE.i+1 AS i
        ,JSON_MODIFY(CTE.paths, N'append $', CTE.i+1) AS paths
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CTE.i < 1000
    AND CTE.i IN
    (
        SELECT
            nda.value
        -- OpenJSON: ALTER DATABASE <db_name()> SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
        FROM OPENJSON(CTE.paths, N'$') AS nda
    )
)
SELECT i FROM CTE 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

but JSON isn't any faster, plus it only works with SQL-Server 2016+.

I also tried with XML:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        1 AS i
       ,CAST(N'<table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><row>1</row>' AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS paths


    UNION ALL


    SELECT 
         CTE.i+1 AS i 
         -- <row xsi:nil="true"/> 
        ,CTE.paths + N'<row>' + CAST((CTE.i + 1) AS nvarchar(36)) + N'</row>' AS paths
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CTE.i < 300
    AND CTE.i IN
    (
        SELECT
            xmlRow.xmlElement.value(N'.', N'int') AS v
        FROM
        (
            SELECT CAST(CTE.paths + N'</table>' AS xml) AS xmlArray
        ) AS tXmlArrayConverter
        CROSS APPLY tXmlArrayConverter.xmlArray.nodes(N'//row') AS xmlRow(xmlElement)
    )

)
SELECT i FROM CTE 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

and while that would work with sql-server < 2016, this is just too damn slow - far worse than like.

The only way to get a decent performance has been switching to PostgreSQL, which supports arrays:

```
;WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        1 AS i 
       ,array[1] AS paths 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
         CTE.i+1 AS i 
        ,CTE.paths || (CTE.i + 1) AS paths
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CTE.i < 10000
    AND CTE.i = ANY(CTE.paths) 
    -- AND CTE.i <> ALL(CTE.paths) 
)
SELECT i FROM CTE
```

this completes in 1.6s, which is about as good as I would expect.

Is there any way to improve performance in SQL-Server ?

**Note:** 
This dumbed-down example with `CTE.i IN (whatever)` is not supposed to make any sense, it's just for speed comparison.

Comment: `LIKE` can be slow, especially when you have a leading wild card. We don't have any sample data or expected results here, so there's not a lot we can do to help you on this. You also state *"Since SQL-Server doesn't support arrays"*, do you mean that you're passing a list to SQL Server? If so, use a Table-Type Parameter.

Comment: @Larnu: No, i mean aggregating ids (of any type) in the recursive join, to use them to prevent infinite cycling. This cannot be done with table-valued parameters, AFAIK.

Comment: What do you mean "aggregating ids"? A `COUNT`? I really don't understand what you're after here. Sample data and expected results will help here.

Comment: @Larnu: Exactly the thing you see in the PG query. paths as array of integers. Because you need them in the where clause to not join elements that have already been added.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105879/graph-problems-connect-by-nocycle-prior-replacement-in-sql-server for a real-life example - that should clear things up.

Comment: *"Exactly the thing you see in the PG query"* I don't know PostgreSQL so that doesn't help me. If you can show sample data and expected results then I can try to help you, but all I have to go on is a query and being told it's performing slow (which i would expect with a leading wild card on a `LIKE` clause). No query plan and no data means there's nothing I can suggest as i have a black box in front of me,

Comment: By `national character varying(MAX)` I assume you meant to write `NVARCHAR(MAX)`? Also, some sample data to work on to understand exactly what you are working on would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @TT.; national character varying(MAX) is SQL-standard. nvarchar is microsoft proprietary sql. but in sql-server, it's just a alias for nvarchar. No sample data needed - just a fast way to avoid cycles in recursive queries. Doesn't depend on the data.